# Flowtype error when using XML classes

Tags: javascript, xml, flowtype

I have a front-end React application, with flow set up.
It has some simple XML-related code:

```
const xmlDoc: XMLDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");

xmlDoc.evaluate(xPath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

However, flow is reporting the following error:

> Cannot resolve name XMLDocument
>
> Cannot resolve name XPathResult

I guess I need to import the class, but I don't know which module it would be defined in. Nor did I find definitions in flow-typed.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you [search the Flow repo on github for "DOMParser"](https://github.com/facebook/flow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DOMParser&type=) it will lead you to [this definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/3157e255425beb3d1c0e213759d623a3aae8f32d/lib/bom.js#L315):

```
declare class DOMParser {
    parseFromString(source: string, mimeType: string): Document;
}
```

So it looks like Flow calls an `XMLDocument` a `Document`, so you just need to adjust your definition a bit:

```
const xmlDoc: Document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");

xmlDoc.evaluate(xPath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Let me know if that works. I didn't check it on my local computer and for some reason or another this doesn't work on https://flow.org/try

P.S. I don't see a definition for `XPathResult` or the `evaluate` method in the Flow `lib` folder, so that's probably not defined right now. Maybe you want to put in a PR to add those?

Comment: Thanks James. I tried it, but now I have the following error:

> Cannot call xmlDoc.evaluate because property evaluate is missing in Document

Comment: Great. Thanks. :)

Comment: Until that lands, maybe just add a [//$FlowFixMe](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) comment above it to document the problem